# How to drag and drop column values in a table/grid?

Tags: asp.net, grid, drag

I have an existing Silverlight application that allows one to click on a column cell and drag to the left or right in the row.  When this is done the value from the original cell is copied into the "dragged over" cells (there could be more than one).  At the same time, a message is sent to the server to trigger a database update.

I now need to port this application to ASP.Net and make it tablet friendly.   I have searched high and low and looked at the various grid providers and through jquery plugins but have not been able to find something that already does this.  Any ideas on existing solutions or how to get started otherwise?

Thanks!

[image: Picture from Existing Silverlight Application]

Comment: I know you said you looked at jQuery plugins, so did you look at jQuery UI Draggable? http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: Based on my previous review, I think the issue is on the Droppable side and being able to put the value in multiple cells.